# using Microsoft interop to fill a letter in Word C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I am Trying out a Program to Fill a Letter in Microsoft Word using Interop in C#.
I have hard coded all the Text that is to be filled in word in my program.

but While running my program I could see that I am not able to use the normal copy and paste option in my computer. While doing so it pastes the text that is copied by my program in clipboard. Is there a solution for this Problem

Answer (score 0):

When modifying a Word document with interop, I use the "replace bookmark" functionality. You define **bookmarks** in your model .doc then replace them with text at runtim with I wrote this function

```
Public Shared Sub ReplaceBookmarkText(ByVal doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByVal bookmarkName As String, ByVal text As String)
    If (doc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName)) Then
        Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range = doc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range
        range.Text = text
        doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, range)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the trouble is while the process is running, I am not able to use the normal copy or paste functionality in my system. The program gets interrupted

Comment: The filling process happens in the background, without actually "seeing" the open document. It's a so called batch process. The interop library opens the .doc behind the scenes and updates its content.

Comment: I agree, just wanted to know If I could do something to stop data in clipboard getting messed up?